# execute powershell command using php

Tags: php, powershell

I have a command which executes properly in powershell command prompt but I am unable run it using php.

Script file is located at "C:\Users\KiranS\Desktop\script1.ps1" and contains function name `Stop-IdleProcess` and it requires parameter `ProcessName`.

Below is powershell command

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -command "&
  {. .\script1.ps1; Stop-IdleProcess -ProcessName 'notepad'}"
```

Comment: what did you try? thats the first thing we need

Comment: I tried using shell_exec function i.e shell_exec ("powershell -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -command "&
 {C:\Users\KiranS\Desktop\script1.ps1; Stop-IdleProcess -ProcessName 'notepad'}"");

Comment: I'm not familiar with using Windows as a php server, but `-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted` would / should not be something that php is allowed to do by default.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the [shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) command.

If your using IIS as your webserver, you can follow this tutorial [here](http://theboywonder.co.uk/2012/07/29/executing-powershell-using-php-and-iis/) to run it

Comment: To be fair, that answer had not showed up when I clicked POST